# Neo4j SDN UUID Transaction Handler

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.7 with SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE in embedded mode.

How can i automatically assign UUIDs to new nodes? What is the best practice when trying to achieve this?

---

*Current Solution:*

I added a TransactionEventHandler which automatically add a uuid property to every node. Additionally this handler also blocks the commit when someone tries to remove the uuid.

*Problems:*

With SDN i always have to reload the entity outside of my transaction in order to use the generated uuid. This limits the usefulness of @Transactional. Is there maybe a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just enhanced my save method in my entity service implementation which will set the uuid upfront when it determined that the given entity is new.

Entity:

```
public boolean isNew() {
    return null == getId();
}
```

EntityServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public T save(T node) {
    if (node.isNew() && node.getUuid() == null) {
        node.setUuid(UUIDTransactionEventHandler.getUUID());
    }
    return nodeRepository.save(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several posibilities

1. Assign the uuid in entity constructor, the advantage of this is that you can then use the uuid safely in **equals** and **hashCode**.

   ```
   MyNodeEntity() {
     uuid = UUID.randomUUID.toString()
     ....
   }
   ```
2. Use [lifecycle events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#lifecycle_events), very useful for cases similar to "add uuid 
   if it is not set"

   ```
   @Bean
   ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
       return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
               MyNodeEntity entity = (MyNodeEntity) event.getEntity();
               if (!entity.hasUuid()) {
                   entity.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID.toString());
               }
           }
       };
   }
   ```
3. Subclass GraphRepository and override save() method - too complicated for something that can be achieved using the lifecycle events